# Android app gets installed 3 times when ran once on android device

Tags: android, android-install-apk

When running my app on my phone it gets installed 3 times, not sure why it does this, anyone know how I can solve this?

my manifest

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MyTravelManagerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OpenMap"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Can you define "Installed 3 times"? Three entries in the app list? Three notifications? Three homescreen icons?

Comment: it appears 3 times in the app list when going to the menu

Comment: Can you post your application manifest?

Comment: SOLVED...think i know what the problem is ...<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Answer (score 4):

The app is installed only once. But you see it 3 times in the application launcher. Each icon in the application launcher corresponds to one of your activities. It is caused by the intent filter you specified for each of the activities:

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

The intent filter says that the activity can be launched and it's icon with a corresponding label should be visible in the application launcher. If you press the icon in the launcher, you will start the corresponding activity. Typically, you have only one such activity in the application.

Btw: Apps on Android are distinguished by the package specified in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Therefore unless you change the package, you can't install the app multiple times.