# App getting installed three times when run through usb debugging after converting my project to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-studio-import

i just converted my eclipse project to android studio project and installed the studio build through the USB debugging.

and i got my app installed three times, if i clicks the first app it gets open the app and if i clicks other 2 apps its get force closed. how do i remove other two same app.

i got one url about this discussion not getting solved my problem

```
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867455/android-app-gets-installed-3-times-when-ran-once-on-android-device
```

Comment: show your android manifest

Comment: only one MAIN in maifect @Virthuss

Comment: thats not the problem ^^ we need it to help you. just post it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your `AndroidManifest.xml` looks like this:

```
         ...
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="..."
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="..."
            android:theme="@style/theme">
            <!--android:label="@string/app_name" >-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

If you have three times

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

You will have three icons as well. Keep this for your main activity, the one you use to launch your app. Remove it for the others.

Comment: Put it as the accepted answer for the people having this problem as well ! good luck for the rest :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes the problem is, my app imports two own libraries which is having main activities, i replaced the main activities from the two libraries. so now the problem getting solved... but in eclipse not like that i think...